# Error exporting from MS SQL Server 2014 Import/Export Wizard to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

Environment is MS SQL Server 2014, Import/Export Wizard 64-bit, trying to export to MySql 5.6.47

I'm using the .Net Framework Data Provider for ODBC & have Installed mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.21-winx64

When running the export, I get the following:

Error 0xc020844b: Data Flow Task 1: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.47]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"shipyards" ("shipyard_id", "shipyard") VALUES (?, ?)' at line 1  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Obviously, I know that "Values (?, ?)" cannot be insert into a table that has an int & varchar(55) column, what I DO NOT GET is why "Values (?,?)" is even being produced (these values are not in the source database).

I'm suspecting a conversion or mapping issue but I've been spinning my wheels for a number of days now trying to find a solution.

Comment: It's probably a prepared statement where ?s represent parameters, just something went wrong with SSIS's execution of the statement. I would venture your table name is not mysql compliant and is not propery encapsulated by backticks. Notice that the code excerpt in the error message starts with the table name, not with the ?s.

Comment: I wouldn't focus on the `VALUES (?, ?)` part of the snippet, it's a prepared statement. Are you transferring data into an existing MySQL database hosted on a case-sensitive file system like ext2, ext3, ext4 on Linux? Database and table names can be case-sensitive when that's true. REF: [Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: @Shadow - thanks for pointing that out, that *is* probably the issue however it's not obvious how to change the default behaviour of the Import Wizard to exclude the the quotes or substitute them with backticks. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: Since this is not a programming error, this question is off topic here. I suggest you either try the dba sister site of SO or the microsoft forums to get help in this matter.